Addition map is continuous under compact convergence topology
Let $X$ be a topological space. Endow $\mathcal C(X,\mathbf R)$ with the compact convergence topology.

Prove: The addition, multiplication and the scalar multiplication
$$\begin{aligned}a:\mathcal C(X,\mathbf R)\times\mathcal C(X,\mathbf R)\to \mathcal C(X,\mathbf R),\ &(f,g)\mapsto a(f,g)=f+g\end{aligned}$$
is continuous.

My attempt: The compact convergence topology is induced by topological basis $\mathcal B=\{B(f,K,\varepsilon)\mid f\in \mathcal C(X,\mathbf R),K\subset X \text{ compact, }\varepsilon>0\}$, where $B(f,K,\varepsilon)=\{g\mid \sup\limits_{x\in K}|f(x)-g(x)|<\varepsilon\}.$ I tried to show that $a^{-1}(B(f,K,\varepsilon)$) is a product basis of $\mathcal C(X,\mathbf R)\times\mathcal C(X,\mathbf R)$, but I failed to do it. I also tried to consider a neighborhood of $f+g\in B(h,K,\varepsilon)$, but failed for similar reason.
Could you give me some hint or help? thx:)

Can't you just prove that if $f_n \to f$ and $g_n\to g$ uniformly on compact subsets of $X$ then the same holds for $f_n + g_n\to f+g$?

@Gribouillis I think that is wrong, since the compact-convergence topology is not a metric topology, so the sequential continuity cannot imply continuity.

According to the answer in this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560978/what-is-topology-of-compact-convergence , one can consider only sequences. Also aren't the sets $B(f, K, \epsilon)$ a subbasis rather than a basis of that topology?
