# Does Arzelà's theorem hold without hausdorfness?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, function-spaces

At the $47$-th paragraph on the text *Topology* by James Munkres is asked to prove the following result

> **Theorem**
>
> If $(X,\cal T)$ is a hemicompact and $\underline{\text{hausdorff}}$ space then any sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\omega}$ of functions from $X$ to $\Bbb R^n$ with $n\in\omega_+$ has a compactly convergent subsequence whether it is equicontinuous and pointwise bounded.

So I proved the above theorem as to follow.

> *Prof*. So if $(f_n)_{n\in\omega}$ is equicontinuous then by definition for any $x\in X$ the set
> $$
> \cal F_x:=\big\{f_n(x):n\in\omega\big\}
> $$
> is bounded so that it has compact clausure and thus by [Ascoli's theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiLtq.png) the set
> $$
> \cal F:=\{f_n:n\in\omega\}
> $$
> is contained in a compact subspace $\cal K$ of $\mathcal C(X,\Bbb R^n)$ equipped with compact convergence topology $\cal T_k$. After all, [by emicompactness](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/432280/736008) we know that $(Y^X,\cal T_k)$ is metrizable so that $\cal K$ is sequentially compact because any subspace of a metrizable space is metrizable and because for metric space compactness and sequential compactness are equivalent. So by sequentially compactness of $\cal K$ we conclude that $(f_n)_{n\in\omega}$ has a subsequence converging to any element $f$ of $\cal K$ or rather of $\mathcal C(X,\Bbb R^n)$.

So it seem I to me I well proved the theorem but it seem to me even I did not use hausdorfness so that I thought to put a specific question where I ask clarification about hausdorfness: so did I well prove the theorem? is actually hausdorfness necessary and did I use it? Could someone help me, please?

**N.B.**

Really Munkres do not requires that $X$ is hemicompact with respect $\cal T$ but $\sigma$-compact: however, $\sigma$-compactness defined by Munkres is not  the classical one but it is a special case of hemicompactness so that I think that this is actually the reason for which hausdorfness is necessary for Munkres but obviously this is only my opinion; anyway, click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn27W.png) if you like to know Munkres $\sigma$-compactness.